# Carousel is merging with the hero image and navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a small website for fun... I have created the Hero Image and Navbar with help from https://www.w3schools.com and also tried adding a Carousel but it seems that it is merging in between of Navbar and Hero Image...

Ref:
[Without Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDq9F.png)

With Carousel: [Merged!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be5Fd.jpg)

What I want to achieve is [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) But it should be below it, not merged in...

I have tried a lot of ways and searched the whole StackOverFlow site, but it seems I have a stupid brain which could not understand this silly problem.

Here is some source code in case you need it:
**CSS**

```
.hero-image{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("heroimage.jpg");
    height: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hero-text{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
nav {
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
}
nav a {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    background-color: 1a1a1a;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #3b86ff;
}
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  z-index:4;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>
        Checkmate - Chess Tournaments Online
        </title>
        <link rel = "icon" href ="CheckmateIcon.jpeg" type = "image/x-icon">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="hero-image">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1 style="font-size:50px">Checkmate</h1>
            <p>Chess Tournaments Online</p>
        </div>
    </div>
                <script>
                    var slideIndex = 1;
                    showSlides(slideIndex);
                        function plusSlides(n) {
                        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
                        }
                        function currentSlide(n) {
                        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
                        }

                        function showSlides(n) {
                        var i;
                        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
                        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
                        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                        slides[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                        }
                        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
                        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
                        }
                </script>>
    <nav>
        <a href=#>Tournaments</a>
        <a href=#>Event Plan</a>
        <a href=#>Register</a>
    <nav>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just tell what I am doing wrong TT_TT

Answer (score 0):

What i can see from here is you are using `position:fixed` on slideshow-container without giving it `top` property. It will stick to `top`

try this

/* Slideshow container */

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  z-index:4;
  top:50px;

}

 <body>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Tournaments</a>
  <a href="#">Event Plan</a>
  <a href="#">Register</a>
  <nav>
    <div class="hero-image">
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1 style="font-size: 50px">Checkmate</h1>
        <p>Chess Tournaments Online</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</nav>


<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img
      src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/05/06/10/27/tulips-6233077__480.jpg"
      style="width: 100%"
    />
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img
      src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/05/06/10/27/tulips-6233077__480.jpg"
      style="width: 100%"
    />
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img
      src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/05/06/10/27/tulips-6233077__480.jpg"
      style="width: 100%"
    />
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br />
<div style="text-align: center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
<script>
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides((slideIndex += n));
  }
  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides((slideIndex = n));
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it, didn't work, the same result.

Comment: though this me the image displayed and it was in front of my navbar and hero image, but now my whole page layout is messed up...and my js buttons are not functioning